# $match for aggregation in mongodb with _id is an object

Tags: mongodb

I query this statement and I got documents

```
db.getCollection('myDocument').aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {"key1": "$key1", "key2": "$key2", "key3": "$key3"}, 
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: { $gte: 3 }
        }
    },
    { $sort : { count : -1} },
]);
```

Then, I add a filter to narrow down the result with a found value from above query. But there is no document

```
db.getCollection('test_driver1').aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {"key1": "$key1", "key2": "$key2", "key3": "$key3"}, 
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: { $gte: 3 },
            _id: {"key1": 1234} // <= 1234 is a found value. what wrong with this condition?
        }
    },
    { $sort : { count : -1} },
]);
```

Comment: Use "_id.key1": 1234

Comment: thx anhlc. It works. Could you create a answer? Then, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve is matching on a [nested field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field).

Try the following:

```
db.getCollection('test_driver1').aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {"key1": "$key1", "key2": "$key2", "key3": "$key3"}, 
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: { $gte: 3 },
            "_id.key1": 1234
        }
    },
    { $sort : { count : -1} },
]);
```